# Max and group by in Mongodb

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

First of all we are just migrating from SQL Server to Mongodb.
I have a collection containing fields `TFN, Impressions`. I need to transform the sql query in mongo but got stuck at a moment.

Scenario is I need to select a `top 5 impressions` from the collection which are `group by on the basis of tfns`

```
Select Top 5 a.TFN, a.MaxImpression as MaxCount from ( 
  Select TFN, Max(Impressions) MaxImpression 
  from tblData 
  Where TFN in (Select TFN From @tmpTFNList) and TrendDate between @StartDate AND @EndDate
  Group by TFN 
  ) a
```

This is the query in Sql Server. I need to achieve the same scenario by using mongodb. So far i have gone through the aggregate and group functions of mongo but couldn't able to achieve the same output as by sql.

**Note: I am just unable to make a link between Max clause and Group by in MongoDb**

Here is the implementation which i have tried

```
db.getCollection("_core.data").aggregate([
       { 
           $match: 
           {
               $and: [
                   {
                       "TFN": 
                       {
                           $in: tfns 

                       }

                   } ,
                   { 
                       "TrendDate": 
                       {
                           $gte : 20170421,
                           $lte: 20170421

                       }
                   }]
           }
        }, 
        {
            $group: 
            {
               _id:"Impressions", 
               Impression: {
                   $max : "$Impressions"
               }
            }  
        }
    ])
```

secondly tried

```
db.getCollection("_core.adwordsPull.static").group({
    key: { TFN: 1,  Impressions: 1 },
    cond: { TFN:  {
                               $in: tfns 

                           },
                       { 
                           "TrendDate": 
                           {
                               $gte : 20170421,
                               $lte: 20170421

                           }
                       } },
    reduce: function( curr, result ) {

                result.total += curr.Impression;
             },
    initial: { total : 0 }
})
```

what is wrong with the approach and how could i correct them?

**Edit 1: Sample Data**

```
TFN Impression  TrendDate
84251456    12  20170424
84251456    15  20170424
84251456    18  20170424
84251456    19  20170424
84251456    22  20170424
84251456    23  20170423
84251456    24  20170423

84251455    25  20170423
84251455    30  20170423
84251455    35  20170424
84251455    24  20170423
84251455    22  20170423
84251455    21  20170424
84251455    22  20170424
```

**Expected Output :**

```
TFN  MaxCount
84251456    22
84251455    35
```

Comment: Your SQL query is grouping by `TFN` but your mongo aggregate `$group` pipeline is grouping by the `Impressions` key, am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve the desired result, start by breaking down the SQL query beginning with the sub query:

```
Select *
from tblData 
Where TFN in (Select TFN From @tmpTFNList) and TrendDate between @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

The equivalent mongo query follows:

```
db.getCollection("_core.data").aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "TFN": { "$in": tmpTFNList },
            "TrendDate": {
                "$gte": startDate,
                "$lte": endDate
            }
        }
    }
])
```

---

The **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** aggregate equivalent of

```
Select TFN, Max(Impressions) MaxImpression 
from tblData 
Where TFN in (Select TFN From @tmpTFNList) and TrendDate between @StartDate AND @EndDate
Group by TFN
```

follows

```
db.getCollection("_core.data").aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "TFN": { "$in": tmpTFNList },
            "TrendDate": {
                "$gte": startDate,
                "$lte": endDate
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$TFN",
            "MaxImpression": { "$max": "$Impression" }
        }
    }
])
```

---

The top 5 query

```
Select Top 5 a.TFN, a.MaxImpression as MaxCount from ( 
    Select TFN, Max(Impressions) MaxImpression 
    from tblData 
    Where TFN in (Select TFN From @tmpTFNList) 
        and TrendDate between @StartDate AND @EndDate
    Group by TFN 
) a
```

is made possible with the **[`$limit`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/#pipe._S_limit)** operator and the fields selection through the **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** stage as

```
db.getCollection("_core.data").aggregate([
    { /* WHERE TFN in list AND TrendDate between DATES */
        "$match": {
            "TFN": { "$in": tmpTFNList },
            "TrendDate": {
                "$gte": startDate,
                "$lte": endDate
            }
        }
    },
    { /* GROUP BY TFN */
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$TFN",
            "MaxImpression": { "$max": "$Impression" }
        }
    },
    { "$limit": 5 }, /* TOP 5 */
    { /* SELECT a.MaxImpression as MaxCount */
        "$project": {
            "TFN": "$_id",
            "_id": 0,
            "MaxCount": "$MaxImpression"
        }
    }
])
```

---

### UPDATE

To get the desired result from the sample in this [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/43585164/4), you need an extra **[`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort)** pipeline before the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** where your sort the documents by the `TrendDate` and `Impression` fields, both in descending order.

You will then have to use the **[`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first)** accumulator operator within the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline stage to get the maximum impression as you will have an ordered stream of documents in your pipeline.

Consider running the revised aggregate operation as:

```
db.getCollection('collection').aggregate([
    { 
        "$match": {
            "TFN": { "$in": tmpTFNList },
            "TrendDate": {
                "$gte": startDate,
                "$lte": endDate
            }
        }
    },
    { "$sort": { "TrendDate": -1, "Impression": -1 } },
    {  
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$TFN",
            "MaxImpression": { "$first": "$Impression" }
        }
    },
    { "$limit": 5 }, 
    {   
        "$project": {
            "TFN": "$_id",
            "_id": 0,
            "MaxCount": "$MaxImpression"
        }
    }
])
```

**Sample Output**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "TFN" : 84251456,
    "MaxCount" : 22
}

/* 2 */
{
    "TFN" : 84251455,
    "MaxCount" : 35
}
```

Comment: the approach is exactly right, but i am not getting maxImpression count there is some issue in group expression either. I am getting the max impression count like 0, 1, 2 not the max value of impressions

Comment: Could you be flexible enough to update your question with some sample documents and your expected output from the sample?

Comment: @HassaanKhan I've updated my answer with the data from the sample, please check.

Comment: this is the best explanation i have got